# Regex Split - escape the same character I use for split

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
string data = "SEQUENCE $FIRST$ THEN $SECOND$ AND FINALLY \\$12345";
```

I want to split it up using Regex using the "$" character.  However, I want to use \ as escape character.

```
string[] sComponents = Regex.Split(data, "(\\$)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

By running the code above I would get:

```
sComponents[0] = "SEQUENCE "
sComponents[1] = "FIRST"
sComponents[2] = " THEN "
sComponents[3] = "SECOND"
sComponents[4] = " AND FINALLY "
sComponents[5] = "12345"
```

But I want sComponents[4] to contain the $ such as " AND FINALLY $12345"

What is the best way to achieve this, does Regex has some type of escape character when splitting? or I have to manually handle this before I call Regex Split with my own logic?

Basically it comes down to, if Regex sees "$" then split but if it sees "\\$" then ignore it don't split at this very position.

Comment: What is the rule that prevents splitting from occurring on the '$' in front of the '12345'? The fact that it's in front of a number, or that there isn't a correspoding '$' at the end?

Comment: I'm thinking of using \\ such as "SEQUENCE $FIRST$ THEN $SECOND$ AND FINALLY \\$12345"

Comment: @Fylix, do you really want to end up with a string array, or do you want to replace things like $FIRST$ and $SECOND$ with other values so you end up with one string that has those things replaced with other values?

Comment: In a large scheme of thing, this is a template I'm writing, so user can type in what they want and put in $ in front and back of a variable name so that I equate it to a value.  But in some case $ is a valid character.  For example: My user name is $USERNAME$ and my password is 12$345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the input string according to the below regex which uses negative lookahead.

```
\$(?!\d)
```

Code:

```
string value = "SEQUENCE $FIRST$ THEN $SECOND$ AND FINALLY $12345";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"\$(?!\d)");
foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/nDRuGS)

**Update:**

Use the below regex to split the input according to the `$` symbol which is not preceeded by two backslashes.

```
(?<!\\\\)\$
```

Code:

```
string value = "SEQUENCE $FIRST$ THEN $SECOND$ AND FINALLY \\\\$12345";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"(?<!\\\\)\$");
foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/6W1qEL)